# Unit Testing Spring ApplicationEvents - Events are getting published but the listeners aren't firing?

Tags: spring

I'm trying to unit test the custom events that I've created in Spring and am running into an interesting problem.  If I create a `StaticApplicationContext` and manually register and wire the beans I can trigger events and see the program flow through the publisher (implements `ApplicationEventPublisherAware`) through to the listener (implements `ApplicationListener<?>`).

Yet when I try to create a JUnit test to create the context using the `SpringJunit4ClassRunner` and `@ContextConfiguration` everything works well except that the ApplicationEvents are not showing up in the listener (I have confirmed that they are getting published).

Is there some other way to create the context so that ApplicationEvents will work correctly?  I haven't found much on the web about unit testing the Spring events framework.

Comment: why there are no answer for this question

Answer (score 2):

The events will not fire because your test classes are not registered and resolved from the spring application context, which is the event publisher.

I've implemented a workaround for this where the event is handled in another class that is registered with Spring as a bean and resolved as part of the test. It isn't pretty, but after wasting the best part of a day trying to find a better solution I am happy with this for now.

My use case was firing an event when a message is received within a RabbitMQ consumer. It is made up of the following:

**The wrapper class**

Note the **Init()** function that is called from the test to pass in the callback function after resolving from the container within the test

```
public class TestEventListenerWrapper {

CountDownLatch countDownLatch;
TestEventWrapperCallbackFunction testEventWrapperCallbackFunction;

public TestEventListenerWrapper(){

}

public void Init(CountDownLatch countDownLatch, TestEventWrapperCallbackFunction testEventWrapperCallbackFunction){

    this.countDownLatch = countDownLatch;
    this.testEventWrapperCallbackFunction = testEventWrapperCallbackFunction;
}

@EventListener
public void onApplicationEvent(MyEventType1 event) {

    testEventWrapperCallbackFunction.CallbackOnEventFired(event);
    countDownLatch.countDown();
}

@EventListener
public void onApplicationEvent(MyEventType2 event) {

    testEventWrapperCallbackFunction.CallbackOnEventFired(event);
    countDownLatch.countDown();
}

@EventListener
public void onApplicationEvent(OnQueueMessageReceived event) {

    testEventWrapperCallbackFunction.CallbackOnEventFired(event);
    countDownLatch.countDown();
}
}
```

The **callback interface**

```
public interface TestEventWrapperCallbackFunction {

void CallbackOnEventFired(ApplicationEvent event);
}
```

**A test configuration class** to define the bean which is referenced in the unit test. Before this is useful, it will need to be resolved from the applicationContext and initialsed (see next step)

```
    @Configuration
public class TestContextConfiguration {
    @Lazy
    @Bean(name="testEventListenerWrapper")
    public TestEventListenerWrapper testEventListenerWrapper(){
        return new TestEventListenerWrapper();
    }
}
```

Finally, **the unit test itself** that resolves the bean from the applicationContext and calls the **Init()** function to pass assertion criteria (this assumes you have registered the bean as a singleton - the default for the Spring applicationContext). The callback function is defined here and also passed to **Init().**

```
    @ContextConfiguration(classes= {TestContextConfiguration.class,
                                //..., - other config classes
                                //..., - other config classes
                                })
public class QueueListenerUnitTests
        extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

    private MessageProcessorManager mockedMessageProcessorManager;
    private ChannelAwareMessageListener queueListener;

    private OnQueueMessageReceived currentEvent;

    @BeforeTest
    public void Startup() throws Exception {

        this.springTestContextPrepareTestInstance();
        queueListener = new QueueListenerImpl(mockedMessageProcessorManager);
        ((QueueListenerImpl) queueListener).setApplicationEventPublisher(this.applicationContext);
        currentEvent = null;
    }

    @Test
    public void HandleMessageReceived_QueueMessageReceivedEventFires_WhenValidMessageIsReceived() throws Exception {

        //Arrange
        //Other arrange logic
        Channel mockedRabbitmqChannel = CreateMockRabbitmqChannel();
        CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        TestEventWrapperCallbackFunction testEventWrapperCallbackFunction = (ev) -> CallbackOnEventFired(ev);
        TestEventListenerWrapper testEventListenerWrapper = (TestEventListenerWrapper)applicationContext.getBean("testEventWrapperOnQueueMessageReceived");
        testEventListenerWrapper.Init(countDownLatch, testEventWrapperCallbackFunction);

        //Act
        queueListener.onMessage(message, mockedRabbitmqChannel);
        long awaitTimeoutInMs = 1000;
        countDownLatch.await(awaitTimeoutInMs, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        //Assert - assertion goes here
    }

    //The callback function that passes the event back here so it can be made available to the tests for assertion
    private void CallbackOnEventFired(ApplicationEvent event){
        currentEvent = (OnQueueMessageReceived)event;
    }
}
```

- **EDIT 1**: The sample code has been updated with CountDownLatch
- **EDIT 2**: Assertions didn't fail tests so the above was updated with a different approach**

Answer (score 2):

I just run my app as SpringBootTest, application events working fine:

```
@TestComponent
public class EventTestListener {

    @EventListener
    public void handle(MyCustomEvent event) {
        // nothing to do, just spy the method...
    }
}

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class MyEventTest {

    @SpyBean
    private EventTestListener testEventListener;

    @Test
    public void testMyEventFires() {
        // do something that fires the event..

        verify(testEventListener).handle(any(MyCustomEvent.class));
    }
}
```

use the @Captor / ArgumentCaptor to verify the content of your event.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a context manually.

For example: I had needed to check if my `ApplicationListener<ContextClosedEvent>` closed Cassandra connections:

```
@Test
public void testSpringShutdownHookForCassandra(){
    ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(CassandraConfig.class);

    CassandraConnectionManager connectionManager = ctx.getBean(CassandraConnectionManager.class);
    Session session = connectionManager.openSession(testKeySpaceName);

    Assert.assertFalse( session.isClosed() );
    ctx.close();

    Assert.assertTrue( session.isClosed() );
}
```